# How to upload image on server's image folder

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc

This is my spring project structure.

[image: Project structure in spring]

I have to upload hotels picture in image folder. But i am not getting path of image folder.I tried below code

```
//There is some code here
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List items = null;
items = upload.parseRequest(request);
Iterator itr = items.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext())
{
    FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
    itemName = item.getName();
    File savedFile = new File(request.getRealPath("/")+"image-folder\\"+itemName);
    item.write(savedFile);
}
```

but it is giving error : Directory not exist.

Now I have two question.

What is solution of above problem?

Is this a right way to upload image in server's image folder? Because it could be temporary i have read on stackoverflow?

Edited:

Runing project from eclipse and when i printed path it gives 
E:\DeepakWork\current\jmx_examples.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\HotelManagment\image(file-name)

Answer (score 0):

I first want to answer the second most important question

> Is this a right way to upload image in server's image folder?

**No, it is not**. Because it is a security issue! Never ever upload any user generated content in the web application folder!
Instead upload the files in some fixed (configured) folder somewhere outside of the Tomcat Directory.

Comment: whats security issues occur?